# When I use LazyColumn, how do I control scrolling?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-jetpack-compose

Now, I use LazyColumn to display a list. In the tweetItem, there is a button. When I click the button, the soft keyboard and Popup will appear. When they appear, I want the LazyColumn can scroll so that the bottom of the clicked item fits the top of the soft keyboard and Popup.

```
    LazyColumn {
        items(tweets) { tweet ->
            TweetItem(tweet)
            divider()
        }
    }
```

```
Popup(
            onDismissRequest = {
                keyboardController?.hide()
                isDialogShown = false
            },
            content = {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable(
                            onClick = { isDialogShown = false },
                            indication = null,
                            interactionSource = remember {
                                MutableInteractionSource()
                            })
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.Transparent),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
                ) {
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = comment,
                        onValueChange = { comment = it },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                            .focusRequester(focusRequester).background(Color.White),
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(focusedBorderColor = Color.LightGray),
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(//软键盘操作
                            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,//键盘类型
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Default
                        ),
                        maxLines = 4,
                        trailingIcon = {
                            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO:发送评论逻辑*/ }) {
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Filled.Send,
                                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.send)
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
                    )
                }
            },
            properties = PopupProperties(
                focusable = true,
                dismissOnBackPress = true,
                dismissOnClickOutside = true
            )
        )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih4gA.png)

I use AndroidView and LazyColumn's state, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I use LazyColumn state to solved the problem temporarily.

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
lazyListState.scrollToItem(index = selectedItemIndex + 1)
```

The item will appear the top of the screen.

At first,I wanted to solve this problem with the Y coordinate. But I found that this way of calculating is too cumbersome.